# ¿Cómo hacer para mostrar en un formcontrol los datos de una variable?

Tags: angular, angular5, material-design, angular-material

Tengo un problema estoy trabajando con angular material pero a la hora de la interpolacion, mi `formcontrol` a pesar de que esta lleno muestra el error `Validators.required` de los `form`... Aquí muestro una parte del `código`

`HTML`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Nombre"  maxlength="20" 
   [formControl]="nombreControl" [value]="nombre">
         <mat-error *ngIf="nombreControl.hasError('required')">
              El nombre es <strong>Requerido</strong>
         </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

mi component.ts

```
export class UsuarioPerfilComponent implements OnInit {
  nombre='Marwin';

 nombreControl = new FormControl('', [
 Validators.required, 
 ]);
```

El resultado es este al darle click al `form`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas utilizando un property binding. Eso solo crea la relación en un solo sentido. Para tu código el contenido del input (y por decantamiento, tu formulario) esta vació.

Existen 2 formas para hacer lo que necesitas:

1) Usando ngModel:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Nombre"  maxlength="20" 
   [formControl]="nombreControl" [(ngModel)]="nombre">
         <mat-error *ngIf="nombreControl.hasError('required')">
              El nombre es <strong>Requerido</strong>
         </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

De esta manera vinculas en ambos sentidos, si la variable se modifica se modifica el input, y si se modifica el input se modifica la variable

2) Ya que estas usando reactive forms, olvidate de la variable nombre, y coloca el valor por defecto al crear el formControl:

```
nombreControl = new FormControl('Marwin', [
    Validators.required, 
  ]);
```

Luego podes modificar el valor con:

```
this.nombreControl.setValue('EL_NUEVO_NOMBRE');
```

y podes leer el valor con:

```
this.nombreControl.value
```

Personalmente te recomiendo la opción 2 ya que de la otra forma estarías haciendo un bindeo innecesario (Salvo que necesites que el valor este también en esa variable por algún otro motivo).